# Minimizing svm dual form

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, svm, numerical-methods, quadratic-programming

I need to minimize the following equation to implement a c-svm
[Objective function to be minimized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQ4qh.png)
I know that I am supposed to implement stochastic sub-gradient descent algorithm to minimize the above objective function but I am not sure how to do it.

Is the following algorithm the correct way to implement the stochastic sub-gradient descent for the above optimization problem?
[My implementation of stochastic sub-gradient descent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r22rw.png)